# Openstack Installation on Ubuntu Non Graphical server edition 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, ppa, cloud, openstack

We are trying to install Openstack on Ubuntu 14.04.1 server edition, single machine installation mode. We are facing an error while adding the repository

The command  `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/ppa` throws the below error

```
Cannot add PPA : 'ppa:cloud-installer/ppa' 
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Also for accurate documentation for Openstack installation on Ubuntu server 14.04.1 , what are the resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bleeding edge PPA's are hosted by the OpenStack Ubuntu **testing** team - the following are actively maintained:

ppa:openstack-ubuntu-testing/icehouse
ppa:openstack-ubuntu-testing/juno
ppa:openstack-ubuntu-testing/kilo

You can enable these using the add-apt-repository command:

Example:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openstack-ubuntu-testing/kilo`

Testing status data can be found [here](https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Openstack_Testing/view/Juno/)

Answer (score 1):

The PPA should be `ppa:cloud-installer/stable`

Comment: There's also ppa:cloud-installer/testing however there have been reports that ppa:cloud-installer/testing is occasionally unreliable compared to ppa:cloud-installer/stable.